# Swift Set type performance inconsistently when inserting data

Tags: swift

This code will generate different result when `RoadmapCardChain`  implement `Hashable`  and `Equatable`  protocol

```
struct RoadmapCardChain: Codable, Hashable, Equatable {
    let start: String
    let end: String
    let styles: String
    
    static func == (lhs: RoadmapCardChain, rhs: RoadmapCardChain) -> Bool {
        let isStyleSame = lhs.styles == rhs.styles
        let isEndSame = lhs.start == rhs.start && lhs.end == rhs.end
        let isToggleEndSame = lhs.start == rhs.end && lhs.end == rhs.start
        print(lhs)
        print(rhs)
        print("result is \(isStyleSame && ( isEndSame || isToggleEndSame ))")
        return isStyleSame && ( isEndSame || isToggleEndSame )
    }
}

let a = RoadmapCardChain(start: "Cafeteria", end: "Payment BIZ", styles: "AECC5C")
let b = RoadmapCardChain(start: "Payment BIZ", end: "Cafeteria", styles: "AECC5C")

var chains: Set<RoadmapCardChain> = []

print(a.hashValue)
print(b.hashValue)

chains.insert(a)
if chains.contains(b) {
    print("contains is true")
} else {
    chains.insert(b)
}

print(chains)
```

sometime result is :

```
785027920194053578
6404817261741129101
RoadmapCardChain(start: "Cafeteria", end: "Payment BIZ", styles: "AECC5C")
RoadmapCardChain(start: "Payment BIZ", end: "Cafeteria", styles: "AECC5C")
result is true
contains is true
[__lldb_expr_19.RoadmapCardChain(start: "Cafeteria", end: "Payment BIZ", styles: "AECC5C")]
```

but sometime result is :

```
491382166321900052
7275567105868021174
[__lldb_expr_21.RoadmapCardChain(start: "Cafeteria", end: "Payment BIZ", styles: "AECC5C"), __lldb_expr_21.RoadmapCardChain(start: "Payment BIZ", end: "Cafeteria", styles: "AECC5C")]
```

I don't know why same codes has different performance

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation of [`Hashable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable) states that:

> Two instances that are equal must feed the same values to Hasher in hash(into:), in the same order.

But you break that requirement, because two objects that are different in their properties (which is what's used to feed the `Hasher`) are deemed to be equal in your implementation of `==`, i.e. in your example `a == b` is `true`, despite having different `.start` and `.end` properties.

Objects being equal (`==`) under `Equatable` conformance mean that one can be substituted for another without any side effects. In your case, they aren't truly equal.

If you do consider them "equal" under some business rule, then you should implement a different comparison method (e.g. `isSimilarTo`) and not change the intent of `==`.

Comment: thanks for your answer,But I still don't understand why sometimes `==` be called and sometimes it doesn't be called。According to my understanding `Set`  only need `hashvalue` when insert or contains function,  don't need to call `==`

Comment: @RookieNeo, I don't know the internal inner-workings. It might create internal copies of elements where the hash sometime matches and sometime diverges (whereas it should always be the same for equals), causing unexpected behavior